# Why does android go to onDestroy() after enabling large text in accessibility?

Tags: android, accessibility

But after going to `onDestroy()`, it would still go through `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`, by then though, some texts are missing and images are gone.

Answer (score 2):

The Android system doesn't magically enlarge all applicable TextViews and custom views with text when you modify large text setting in accessibility. Instead it recreate the application with a new [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html). If you are experiencing data loss afterwards, it means you should study [Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) some more.

There are all kinds of situations where an Activity would be destroyed & recreated by the Android OS, so you should really understand it to create a well-behaving app.